# How to fix 'tsc: command not found'

Tags: typescript, npm, command-line

I'm currently trying to install typescript on my machine for the first time. After installing node I run the following command:

```
sudo npm -g install typescript
```

This yields what appears to be a positive install message

> /Users/mac/.npm-global/bin/tsc ->
>   /Users/mac/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
>   /Users/mac/.npm-global/bin/tsserver ->
>   /Users/mac/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver
>   + typescript@3.4.4 updated 1 package in 0.924s

After this, I check to see if the install was successful but running `tsc --version` and receive the following error:

```
tsc: command not found
```

From another thread I have tried:

restarting the terminal
restarting the machine
reinstalling nodejs + then run `sudo npm install typescript -g`

I have also tried updating my bash profile with the following line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:"/Users/mac/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc"";
```

I am not confident typescript resides in the location I listed. Is there a way to confirm?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I have also tried updating my bash profile with the following line` You should've added the path to the bin directory, not to the executable itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for the extremely prompt and helpful response. This was, in fact, the issue. Changing my bash profile to /Users/mac/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin immediately solved the issue.

Comment: @tkausl: You might post that as an answer -- or perhaps the question should be closed or deleted.

Comment: `sudo` makes root run the install. You probably want to install under _your own_ home directory, not under root's; there's no need for `sudo` in that case.

Answer (score 4):

The following issue was fixed pretty easily. From your terminal open your bash profile:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

Edit your path to direct to the bin and not the executable (your path may vary see path after install):

```
/Users/mac/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/
```

Save and close your file.

Reload your bash profile:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Confirm all is working by checking the version:

```
tsc -v
```

Answer (score 4):

(2020) This helped for me
`npx tsc app.ts`

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that the "tsc" command is not found, which indicates that the TypeScript compiler (tsc) is not installed or not available in your system's PATH. To fix this issue, you need to ensure that TypeScript is installed and accessible. Here's what you can do:

1. Install TypeScript globally using npm:

   ```
   npm install -g typescript
   ```

   This command will install TypeScript globally on your system.
2. Verify the installation by running:

   ```
   tsc --version
   ```

   It should display the installed TypeScript version if the installation was successful.
3. If you already had TypeScript installed but it's not in your system's PATH, you can try adding it manually:

   - For macOS/Linux:

     - Open your shell configuration file (e.g., `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.zshrc`).
     - Add the following line at the end of the file:

       ```
       export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
       ```
     - Save the file and restart your terminal or run `source <file_path>` to apply the changes.
   - For Windows:

     - Open the Environment Variables settings.
     - Edit the "Path" variable and add the path to the TypeScript installation directory (e.g., `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm`).
     - Save the changes and restart your terminal or open a new command prompt to apply the changes.

Once TypeScript is successfully installed and accessible, you should be able to run the `tsc` command without any issues.

Comment: This answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still trying and want a fresh answer, I will suggest do the following. If it still shows `"tsc: command not found"` in your terminal, do:

`cd ~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin`

then do `pwd` to get the absolute path of the directory

once you `pwd`, copy what it shows and type this to your profile:

`export PATH=$PATH:<your_pwd_directory_path_that_you_copied>`

restart your terminal and rerun `tsc -v` or `tsc --version` and it should work out

Answer (score -4):

May be this can help you

First type

```
npm bin -g
```

Add the execution result of the above command to your PATH.

```
export PATH=""
```

Hope this may help to solve your problem, And if not let me know.