# bash command for tsc is returning not found

Tags: node.js, bash, typescript, npm

I used the following command to install Typescript:

`npm install -g typescript`

to check the version of typescript I typed in `tsc -v` into the terminal. I received a `tsc command not found` error message. I've used various resources to fix this problem and have been unsuccessful. I've concluded that this might be an issue with the way my bash commands have been set up.

The output for `npm config get prefix` returns `/Users/$user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node`. Within that file, I've found that tsc has been installed. How do I configure my bash command so that tsc works?

Comment: Did You tried to use newer version of node ???

Comment: I think there's many answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404922/tsc-command-not-found-in-compiling-typescript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767486/how-to-fix-tsc-command-not-found and many more.